# Getting Grunt.js to run node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, node-modules

I have written a node.js module that can be run either from file using 'require' or by running node copyright.update() from the terminal.  I'm happy with this functionality and it works in both cases.  I want to also be able to run it from Gruntfile.js.

Currently my grunt file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        "update-copyright": {
            "run": true
        }
    });

    grunt.task.loadTasks('./runner');
};
```

And the script in the runner directory looks like this:

```
var copyright = require('./update-copyright');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerMultiTask('update-copyright', 'update copyright headers', function() {
        var done = this.async();
        copyright.update(done);
    });
};
```

When I run 'grunt update-copright' I get the usual Done, without errors but nothing has actually been executed.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your task completely synchronous?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  It's completely async.  Is that the issue?

Comment: Thanks @IgorRaush - that fixed it!

Comment: Grunt will kill the process before your task has a chance to do anything. Looks like that was the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by Igor Raush I got it to run with:

```
var copyright = require('./update-copyright');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerMultiTask('update-copyright', 'update copyright headers', function() {
        var done = this.async();
        copyright.update(done);
    });
};
```